# java: String.format with PageFactory

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

This is My String in non `PageFactory` framework, declared at the class level.

```
private final String fruits= "//a/h4[text()='%s']";
```

Which is used in same class in some method like this:

```
public void clickFruitHeading(String string) {
        driver.click(By.xpath(String.format(fruits, string)));
        driver.click(By.xpath(String.format(fruits, "Apple")));
    }
```

But when using `PageFactory` it is written like this:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//a/h4[text()='%s']")
private static WebElement fruits;
```

How to use `String.format` here?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do it with `PageFactory` without re-implementing it. Locators to page object elements in `@FindBy` annotations cannot be updated at runtime. You probably would like to have something like

```
fruits("Apple").click();
```

However, the proxy created by `PageFactory` for `fruits` field accessor does not take any arguments. It just does something like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/h4[text()='%s']");
```

The closest thing that you can do is to refrain from using `@FindBy` for this particular element on a Web page, define a method:

```
private WebElement fruits(String fruit) {
  By.xpath(String.format("//a/h4[text()='%s']", fruit));
}
```

and then call it:

```
fruits("Apple").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

The PageFactory code isn't working because fruits isn't a WebElement to be found on the page as is, which is what that scheme is used for.  Instead, it is a string substitution template and should be kept as just a "private final String".